# rounded corners in Qooxdoo - problems with ImageMagick and PNG

Tags: png, imagemagick, qooxdoo

I want to create a button with rounded corners in Qooxdoo but I'm having some problems. I guess it's a problem with ImageMagick and not my Qooxdoo code, but I'll post it anyway.

So in order to create rounded corners I'm following this [guide](http://qooxdoo.org/documentation/1.1/image_clipping_and_combining?s=image%20clipping).

this is what my image.json contains:

```
{
 "jobs" :
 {
  "common" :
  {
   "let" :
   {
    "RESPATH" : "source/resource/custom"
   },

   "cache" :
   {
    "compile" : "../cache"
   }
  },

  "image-clipping" :
  {
     "extend" : ["common"],

     "slice-images" :
     {
     "images" :
     {
     "${RESPATH}/image/source/groupBox.png" :
     {
     "prefix" : "../clipped/groupBox",
     "border-width" : 4
     }
     } 
     }
  },

  "image-combine" :
  {
     "extend" : ["common"],

     "combine-images" :
     {
     "images" :
     {
     "${RESPATH}/image-combined/combined.png":
     {
     "prefix" : [ "${RESPATH}" ],
     "layout" : "vertical",
     "input"  :
     [
      {
         "prefix" : [ "${RESPATH}" ],
         "files" : [ "${RESPATH}/image/clipped/groupBox*.png" ]
      }
     ]
     }
     }
     }
  }
 } 
}
```

Here's what happens when I run image-clipping and image-combine:

> > C:\custom>generate.py -c image.json image-clipping
>
> ```
> INITIALIZING: CUSTOM
> ```
>
> Configuration: image.json
>
> Jobs: image-clipping
>
> Resolving config includes...
>
> Resolving jobs...
>
> Incorporating job defaults...
>
> Resolving macros...
>
> Resolving libs/manifests...
>
> ```
> EXECUTING: IMAGE-CLIPPING
> ```
>
> > > > Initializing cache...
> > > >
> > > > Done
>
> C:\custom>generate.py -c image.json
>   image-combine
>
> ```
> INITIALIZING: CUSTOM
> ```
>
> > > > Configuration: image.json
> > > >
> > > > Jobs: image-combine
> > > >
> > > > Resolving config includes...
> > > >
> > > > Resolving jobs...
> > > >
> > > > Incorporating job defaults...
> > > >
> > > > Resolving macros...
> > > >
> > > > Resolving libs/manifests...
>
> ```
> EXECUTING: IMAGE-COMBINE
> ```
>
> > > > Initializing cache...
> > > >
> > > > Combining images...
>
> - Creating image C:\custom\source\resource\custom\image-combined\combined.png
>     Magick: no decode delegate for this
>     image format
>     `\docume~1\lomme\lokala~1\ tmpql73hk'
>     @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532.
>     Magick: missing an image filename`
>     C:\custom\source\resource\custom\image-combined\combined.png' @
>     error/montage.c/MontageImageCommand/1707.
>     The montage command (montage -geometry
>     +0+0 -gravity NorthWest -tile 1x -background None
>     @c:\docume~1\lomme\lokala~1\temp\tmpql73hk
>     C:\custom\source\resources\custom\image-combined\combined.png)
>     failed with the following return code:1

The image-clipping works like a charm but I get some kinda error message when I try to run image-combine. When I google the error messages it says ImageMagick is lacking PNG support but I can use other commands like "convert a.jpg b.png" so there must be some kinda png support?

here's what "identify -list format" returns:

> ```
> PNG* PNG rw-   Portable Network Graphics (libpng 1.2.43)
>                       See http://www.libpng.org/ for details 
>                       about the PNG format.
> ```
>
> PNG24* PNG rw-   opaque 24-bit RGB (zlib 1.2.3)
>
> PNG32* PNG rw-   opaque or transparent 32-bit RGBA
>
> ```
> PNG8* PNG rw-   8-bit indexed with optional binary
>                       transparency
> ```

So why do i get this error message: 
Magick: no decode delegate for this image format

Looks to me like there's png support? I've never used ImageMagick before so I'm completely lost :D

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you've probably hit what I would consider a bug in newer ImageMagic versions. You neither gave your qooxdoo nor your ImageMagic version, but that's what I'm guessing from the error message. There is a [qooxdoo issue](http://bugzilla.qooxdoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3742) relating to this, which contains a patch that fixes the problem. It is already in the our development versions (trunk and 1.1.x), but you might not want to upgrade to any of them (if you consider this, go for 1.1.x). The alternative would be applying the patch on top of your existing qooxdoo installation. This should be easy, as it is a single-file patch with only local effects. Look for the file `ImageClipping.py` under the `tool/pylib/generator` path in qooxdoo.